# Style html elements dynamically based on id

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to color different elements based on their own ids. If their id is in a list of id's given by me, make it a color, if not, make it another color.

In the example below are 4 div's, each a different color. How can I color each div depending on his id without defining css rules for each of them?

```
const Main = () => {
return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <div id='1' style={{background: 'red'}}>1</div>
    <div id='2' style={{background: 'blue'}}>2</div>
    <div id='3' style={{background: 'green'}}>3</div>
    <div id='4' style={{background: 'cyan'}}>4</div>
  </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9debt3cL/19/

If the question is not very clear, let me know.

UPDATE: Context: I have an svg blueprint divided into multiple parts, each with a unique number. I have to fetch some data containing some parts of the blueprint numbers and depending on those numbers to fill the blueprint paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not completely sure if it would work but you could always try, look into a switch case using javascript. Set the expression and have different cases depending on the value etc. Can be Id in this example and have a different outcome depending on the case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think Wanz has the right approach, you can create css classes with the desired attributes. Then add this class to the dom element if it corresponds to the switch case.
Like so:

```
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  switch (expr) {
  case 'id1':
  element.classList.add("styleId1");
  break;
  case 'id2':
  element.classList.add("styleId2");

  case 'id3':
  element.classList.add("styleId3");

  break;
  default:
    console.log(`no matching id`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this:

```
const Main = () => {
  const coloredIds = ['1', '4'];

  const getBackgroundColor = (id) => {
     return coloredIds.includes(id) ? 'cyan' : 'red';
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div id='1' style={{background: getBackgroundColor('1')}}>1</div>
      <div id='2' style={{background: getBackgroundColor('2')}}>2</div>
      <div id='3' style={{background: getBackgroundColor('3')}}>3</div>
      <div id='4' style={{background: getBackgroundColor('4')}}>4</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

or if you have multiple colors

```
const getBackgroundColor = (id) => {
  switch (id) {
    case '1':
      return 'red';
    case '2':
      return 'blue;
    case '3':
      return 'green';
    case '4':
    default:
      return 'cyan';
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be nice if I would not have to pass the id manually in getBackgroundColor, but somehow take it from the tag. I don't think if it's possible tho.

Comment: @Ghost, indeed, it's probably not possible to access the element's id tag using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a updated jsfiddle of your attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/fyLab6zr/21/

Not sure it's exactly what you wanted, but the colors is specified in the css, so the list of ids that should give certain colors, as well as a default color for all those that do not match:

```
.background {
  background: red;
}

.background-1, .background-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.background-3, .background-4 {
  background: green;
}
```

And then you have a list of ids that you can iterate over to populate the specific ids rows.
Passing in the id in `background-${id}` to set the className equal to the corresponding id. It will then be styled if it exist, or use the fallback 'background' class

```
const Main = () => {
const ids= [1,1,3,2,1,3,4,5, 6, 1]
return (
    <React.Fragment>
    {ids.map((id) => {
        return <div id={id} className={`background background-${id}`}>{id}</div>  
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

**Edit:**

This approach creates your predefined lists of ids, in this example two lists, leading to two different colors. It still defaults back to `background` if none match. The `getColor` function gives the correct `className` based on id. And you can also predefine as many elemnts as you want.

```
const color1 = [1,2]
const color2 = [3,4]

const getColor = (id) => {
   return color1.includes(id) ? 1 : color2.includes(id) ? 2 : -1
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div id="1" className={`background background-${getColor(1)}`}>1</div>
        <div id="2" className={`background background-${getColor(2)}`}>2</div> 
        <div id="3" className={`background background-${getColor(3)}`}>3</div>   
        <div id="4" className={`background background-${getColor(4)}`}>4</div> 
        <div id="5" className={`background background-${getColor(5)}`}>5</div> 
    </React.Fragment>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: This approach forces you to create div's equal to the number of elements in ids. I want to define some divs with predefined ids and color those already defined divs based on a list of ids. Maybe color only one div out of them all if only one id is in the list or every div and so on...

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. Still not sure if I understood it correctly.

Comment: No. I understand your approach, but it is not what I was thinking about. You went the same way as @Neeko. If you do it like this, you manually need to pass each id to getColor function. It would have been nice if it could automatically get the element's id so you don't have to specify it 2 times. This works fine if you already know the ids that are going to be in the lists.

Comment: Thing is, you're not able to get the element's id at that place. If you pass in an element's id from some outside source through `id={someIdParameter}`, you could also pass that one inside the `getColor()`, though it wouldn't change much. It's hard to give an accurate answer without seeing the entire codebase.

Comment: Well, I can't give the codebase cause of inside privacy policy. I can say what I want to use it for: I have an svg blueprint divided into multiple parts, each with a unique number. I have to fetch some data containing some parts of the blueprint numbers and depending on those numbers to fill the blueprint paths.